# Laravel app hosted on Heroku with a Amazon RDS MySQL Database results in a connection time out

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, heroku

I have a Heroku app where I'm hosting my Laravel app. I started the development initially with MySQL, so I wanted to continue doing so using Amazon's RDS service. I create the instance there and managed to successfully connect via my MySQL client, the console etc.

The problem is that the Laravel app can't connect the database after numerous desperate attempts for me to fix it. I have found some articles suggesting the use of `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is mandatory, so I added it via the Heroku app settings. It looks like so:

```
mysql://myusername:mypass@myhostnamefromamazon/mydb?sslca=/app/storage/certs/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem
```

[I found this solution on Heroku's website.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds) I have placed the `amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem` file on my Laravel's storage folder, like so: `/app/storage/certs/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem`

This didn't solve my issue, so then I kept looking and found a [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913743/connecting-heroku-lumen-app-to-amazon-rds-mysql-5-7-19) which had this issue on Lumen. I adjusted my `config/database.php` according to the answer, but it's still not working for me!

```
<?php

$credentials = get_db_credentials();

$config = [
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', $credentials->host),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', $credentials->database),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', $credentials->username),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', $credentials->password),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
    ],
];

if (env('APP_ENV') == 'production') {
    $config['connections']['mysql']['options'] = [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '../storage/certs/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem'];
}

return $config;
```

The `get_db_credentials()` function simply parses the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

The exact exception that I get is:

```
[2018-10-25 19:32:16] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out at /tmp/build_05920c42a6de0a378402b798320d3f04/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:50
```

I'm totally lost on this and unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Do your RDS instance's security groups permit traffic from Heroku's IP space?

Comment: I don't know. How do I check that?

Comment: If you don't know, you didn't do it. You need to permit the traffic in the AWS Console, under EC2's "Security Groups" section. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds for details.

Comment: That fixed it! I guess I missed that part. You may post this as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AWS Security Groups must permit traffic from Heroku's IP address range.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds

> You must grant Heroku dynos access to your RDS instance. The recommended way to do this is to configure the RDS instance to only accept SSL-encrypted connections from authorized users and configure the security group for your instance to permit ingress from all IPs, eg `0.0.0.0/0`.